# Fresh debian squeeze software raid install wont boot

Tags: boot, software-raid, mdadm, grub

I am following these instructions:
http://www.iprobot.net/linux-tutorial/how-to-setup-software-raid-in-debian-ubuntu/

(I used debian-live-6.0.6-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso and DD'd that onto a usb key, booted that and went with a text install)

Having lots of trouble. Tried the same thing in a virtual machine. This is what I get.
[image]

maybe part of the problem is that the /dev/disk/by-uuid area is not populated?

[image]

What should I do?